# VS 2017 .NetCore MSBuild custom task fails to load Newtonsoft.Json or other dependents

Tags: msbuild, json.net, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

**Environment**

Visual Studio 2017

.NET Standard 2.0

.NET Framework 4.6.1

MyCustomTask.csproj contains custom MS build tasks and has multi targets to generate a separate dll for .NET Full and .NEt Core runtime.

[image]

There is a 3 level dependency on the Nuget Package "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" which in turn has a dependency to Newtonsoft.Json package. as shown below.

[image]
[image]

The build is all fine and the Nuget package for **MyCustomTask** is generated successfully.

When I install my MyCustomTask Nuget package on target project then the custom build task is getting successfully executed on .NET Full runtime from Visual Studio 2017, *but for .NET Core **dotnet build** command fail to execute the custom build task...*

**System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral.**

Even if I package all the dependent DLL and place it in same directory of the .netstandard custom task dll I keep getting same error.

Any thoughts how this can be resolved ?

Comment: I think you need to use the 9.* version of newtonsoft.json because msbuild may already have loaded the one it needed to process nuget's assets file and the DLL in the msbuild version has a higher priority

Comment: @MartinUllrich, thanks but I do not have any reference to newtonsoft.json. I just reference to Micorosoft.Extension.Configuration.Json and that has a dependency on newtonsoft.json. My understanding is that for .NET Core depedencies are resolved from Nuget cache so why MSBuild is using an older version (9.*) when my Nuget package says that needs (>= 10.0.1) ?

Comment: These dependency resolution stragegies aren't used in msbuild. msbuild only loads the DLL specified in `<UsingTask>` directly and tries to load additional DLLs from the same directory if it can't find things. a consuming package also shouldn't need to restore additional packages. And the same msbuild task could be used from "full framework" msbuild (visual studio) where there is no .net core dependency probing logic

Comment: Ok I added an explicit reference of Newtonsoft.Jason to my task dll and included it in the package so that the DLL and its dependencies is in the same folder. I am still getting the same error, which you mentioned earlier that MSBuild version has a higher priority. So what can I do then? How do I tell MSbuild to use the latest version Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.1) so that I use Micorosoft.Extension.Configuration.Json (2.0) in my task dll !

Comment: you can use https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.MSBuildExtension to get an isolated task environment

Comment: @MartinUllrich, you are indeed correct. That has fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a solution here for those who are experiencing the same issue.

Credit to **@MartinUllrich** for posting the solution in a comment above. This saved me a lot of trouble.

https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.MSBuildExtension

Ensure your custom task inherits from `ContextIsolatedTask` and copy the dependent assemblies to same directory as your task assembly.